# Why MUI CSS theme variables is still experimental?

Tags: material-ui

I am planning to migrate from Material UI Theme provider to MUI CSS theme variables.
I am wondering Since when was it introduced? and Why is it still experimental and not ready to use without risk?
I could'nt find any reason in docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since when was it introduced?

CSS theme variables for MUI were introduced in [V5.6.0](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/releases/tag/v5.6.0) (around 6 Apr '22). They were introduced as an experimental feature, alongside other experimental features.

> Why is it still experimental and not ready to use without risk?

It has probably not matured enough to be considered stable, and has cons that come alongside its pros, and thus [is not enabled by default](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/releases/tag/v5.6.0). This doesn't mean that you can't adopt it, whatever your use case may be. You'll just have to consider whether it is the right time for you to migrate and if any potential risks or cons are worth it.